# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to make a table and this error comes up. What do I have to fix?

```
mysql> create database mytest;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| mytest             |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
+--------------------+

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> use mytest;
Database changed
mysql> create table price(NAME varchar2(60), PRICE number(10));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar2(60), PRICE number(10))' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are more errors in your statement:

1) you must use backticks if you use keywords as field names like `name`

2) there is no datatype VARCHAR2 use VARCHAR instead

3) there is no datatype NUMBER use INT instead:

```
CREATE TABLE price (
    `NAME` VARCHAR(60),
    `PRICE` INT(10)
);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE price (
    ->     `NAME` VARCHAR(60),
    ->     `PRICE` INT(10)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,03 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `number(10)` by `INTEGER(10)`. There is no data type named `number` in `mysql`.

Comment: also VARCHAR2 is unknown a NAME must be in backticks